# Live555 Server Stream to VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming

I am starting the live555MediaServer.exe on my computer, (no firewalls), it says use url:

rtsp://192.168.1.200/ to refer to a file

in VLC i am entering

rtsp://192.168.1.200/space.mp4

or

rtsp://192.168.1.200/space.h264

However nothing happens, is there any further setup needed for LIVE555?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone had the same problem, you need to have an elementary stream. Furthermore the ending should be ".264" without h.

For more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090114/what-does-elementary-stream-mean-in-terms-of-h264